# how to retrieve Nsstring value from Nsobject?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring, nsobject

i have small doubt in retrieve value from Nsobject class.Firstly i handling login check condition, when i press login button i get response from web service in Nslog, in that i have to capture a string called LoginStatus wether its success r failure.i created NSObject class and its contains one one String,my NSObject class name response_value

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *Loginstatus;
```

now in web service class:

```
response.Loginstatus =[[[json valueForKey:@"login_response"]valueForKey:@"status"]objectAtIndex:0];

NsLog (@"%@",response.Loginstatus);
```

my requested string values are stored in response.LoginStatus string successfully.

But my actual problem is stating in my Login ViewController

i set an condition to check login status if login success means i need to show alert msg either for success r for failure

```
response_value *response = [[response_value alloc]init];
if ([response.response.Loginstatus isEqualToString:@"Login Successfull"]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:response.loginStatusString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

but this condition never getting called and i also checked wether the NSObject string holds any values but the values are null in Nslog

can someone fix my problem

Comment: `response_value *response = [[response_value alloc]init];` Seems to be a complet new object and not the one you got from your web service.

Comment: i did same steps to store value in web service class also, value gets stored in web service class,but when i reuse the string to my Viewcontroller it returns NUll

Comment: Your issue is about OOP. Doing an alloc/init should create a whole new object. Let's says that alloc/init is the same as clicking on the "print button of a blank page". If you press print, a whole blank page will show. You write with a pencil on it (i.e. setting loginstatus value). Pressing again on print will show a new whole blank page. But it doesn't have the previous drawing, that's a new page.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is

```
response_value *response = [[response_value alloc] init];
response.Loginstatus =[[[json valueForKey:@"login_response"]valueForKey:@"status"]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then, pass the `response` object to your `myLoginViewController` and re use it instead of declaring a entire new object for `response_value` inside the `myLoginViewController`.

Comment: can u please update exact code how u pass response to my view controller ?

Comment: c instead of passing to my view controller i need to store the response value in NSObject class so tat i can retrieve whenever i want

Comment: i already tried ur method @Ramshad but still Liam getting null value only